# How to remove html tags in Oracle SQL?

Tags: html, sql

[The following is a part of html tag in oracle db.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lia5j.png)

I used this expression     DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(A.NTT_CN, '<[^>]*>|&([^;])*;', ''), 300, 1)
but all tags were not removed..
Which REGEXP_LIKE expression should I use??

Comment: `<[^>]>` means `<` followed by a single character that isn't `>`, followed by `>`. For most tags you'll need something more like `<[^>]+>`, where `+` is "at least one`

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern : </?[^>]*>

Pattern Explanation from https://regex101.com

- < matches the character < literally (case sensitive)
- /? matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
- ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Match a single character not present in the list below [^>]*
- Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

> matches the character > literally (case sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `SELECT regexp_replace(your_string_here, '(<([^>]+)>)')`

```sql
select 
    original,
    regexp_replace(original, '(<([^>]+)>)') as test
from (select 
        '<span style="font-size: 16pt; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">"example text"</span><p style="font-size: medium; margin-top: 5px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span style="font-size: 12pt;"><b>example text</b>'  as original
      from dual) b;
```

Results: `"example text"example text`